# Is there a finite group with nontrivial $H^2$ but vanishing $H^4$, $H^5$, and $H^6$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Is there a finite group $G$ such that the group cohomology $\mathrm{H}^2_{\mathrm{gp}}(G; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ is nontrivial but $\mathrm{H}^4_{\mathrm{gp}}(G; \mathbb{Z}/2)$,  $\mathrm{H}^5_{\mathrm{gp}}(G; \mathbb{Z}/2)$, and  $\mathrm{H}^6_{\mathrm{gp}}(G; \mathbb{Z}/2)$ all vanish? [I don't care about $\mathrm{H}^1$ or $\mathrm{H}^3$.]

I know that it is hard to arrange groups with lots of vanishing low cohomology: for example, before [Milgram, The cohomology of the Mathieu group $M_{23}$, *Journal of Group Theory*, 2006](https://doi.org/10.1515/jgth.2000.008), one could reasonably conjecture that a nontrivial finite group must have cohomology in degree $\leq 5$.

The reason I ask is because I am trying to engineer a topological field theory with some specific properties. This would be easiest if I had a group as in the question, as then certain obstructions to the construction will automatically vanish.

Comment: When you say that a group $G$ "must have cohomology in degree $\le 5$": you mean that $H^i(G,\mathbf{Z}/2)$ is nonzero for some $1\le i\le 5$? (I'm aware you then provide a counterexample, it's just to understand the assertion.)

Comment: @YCor Yes, sorry to be unclear. Since people sometimes say that something "has no cohomology", it made sense to my ear to say instead that it "has cohomology".

Comment: For what it's worth, if your H4 and H6 vanish then so must H1 (2007 paper of Angelina Chin), so G doesn't have a normal subgroup of index 2.

Comment: @ChrisGerig's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403116/is-there-a-finite-group-with-nontrivial-h2-but-vanishing-h4-h5-and-h#comment1032172_403116), I think:  [Chin - On orders and vanishing of integral cohomology groups](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2007.03.019).